# Warning: Error in result_create: no such column: V2

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm trying to use a database query in R via `sqldf`. But this is giving me error,  due to structure of dataset in my `tss.txt` file. There is no `V1`, `V2`, `V3` in `tss.txt`. But my purpose is to select all rows where `Column No. 01` have value `1`. Can anyone suggest me aproper way of doing this? I cannot find proper solution in Google. Thanks in advance.

***tss.txt:***

```
1 2s 3
1 7s 1s
4 5 6s
1 8s 9s
```

***file.R:***

```
file <-"street_fold4_train.txt"
    res <- read.csv.sql(file, sql = "select * from file where V1=1")
    print(res)
```

It is giving me error:

> Warning: Error in result_create: no such column: V2   86:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to specify the header = FALSE if there isn't a header, then specify the sep based on your input file. The code below works for me.

```
res <- read.csv.sql(file, header = FALSE, sql = "select * from file where V1=1", 
                sep = " ")
```